# Помогите получить значение из списка

Tags: python

Помогите получить значение из списка, который появляется при выполнении команды, и вывести его. Я хочу получить значение "buyprice", которое стоит первым после "price", т.е. 0.05795

```
order = session.place_active_order(symbol=asset, side="Sell", order_type="Market", qty=q, time_in_force="GoodTillCancel")


{'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': {'order_id': '33a6eaec-0768-4368-9d96-848a418ec59d', 'user_id': 36805748, 'symbol': 'RVNUSDT', 'side': 'Buy', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0.05795, 'qty': 20, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Created', 'last_exec_price': 0, 'cum_exec_qty': 0, 'cum_exec_value': 0, 'cum_exec_fee': 0, 'reduce_only': False, 'close_on_trigger': False, 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2022-09-16T04:27:53Z', 'updated_time': '2022-09-16T04:27:53Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'position_idx': 1}, 'time_now': '1663302473.683173', 'rate_limit_status': 99, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1663302473674, 'rate_limit': 100}
```

> buyprice = ........

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы получили - выглядит не как список, а как словарь, и в таком случае

```
buyprice = order['result'] ['price']
```

Comment: давно пробовал:  NameError: name 'price' is not defined

Comment: Присмотрелся повнимательнее - у вас там вложенный словарь, оказывается, так что нужно сначала получить result, а уже из него извлечь price

Comment: получилось :D спасибо большое, двое суток голову ломал спать не мог